# Difference between Extension methods and Methods in C#

Tags: c#, methods, extension-methods

What is the difference between `Extension Methods` and `Methods` in C#?

Comment: I think it's all about Readability and Chaining...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are really looking for is the difference between [Static and Instance Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

At the end of the day Extension methods are some nice compiler magic and syntactic sugar that allow you to invoke a Static method as though it were a method defined on that particular class instance. However, it is ***NOT*** an instance method, as the instance of that particular class must be passed into the function.

Answer (score 4):

ExtensionMethods : Let you define set of methods to a class without subclassing another benefit over inheritance.

Methods : They are used for implementation of operation defind for the the class.

[See example of Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: You can still call an extension method as if it was a normal method. You're not restricted to calling it off the class it extends.

Answer (score 3):

One really nice feature of extension methods is that they can be called on null objects, see this:

```
myclass x = null;
x.extension_method(); // this will work
x.method(); // this won't
```

It is a pity, that for example most methods of **string** are not extension methods, after all

```
x.ToLower();
```

should return null if **x** is null. I mean, it would be useful.

When I need such null-transparency I prefer writing extension methods.

Comment: This is just a personal practice, but I never write null-checking into my extension methods as I expect them to behave like any other instance method and throw a `NullReferenceException` when called on a null object. It's just intuitive that `null.Something` should always throw an exception.

Comment: @Extragorey, today, my answer regarding null has much less ground, since you can have check against null and later use `.?` operator in uniform way.

Comment: True, the `?.` makes null checking much easier, though there are always places where you don't think to use it or don't expect something to be null.